# How to send multiple gridview rows to another page and populate those rows in the repeater?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater showing the rows of data.I have used javascript for user to add new rows to the repeater.

When the new row gets added, a image is displayed on one of the cells .Clicking on that image opens up a new screen.

New screen has ability to search for the records.The search results are shown in a datagrid.

When the user click any of the rows, the same data gets added to the newly added row in repeater of the parent page.

I wish to make this functionality so that mulitple resources can be added at once.
I have put in the check boxes on every row and a button. Button click will add all the checked rows to the repeater in the parent page.

Can you tell me how to handle these multiple rows when sending to the parent page ?

I am using parent.opener to call and pass the values to the parent page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the data of selected rows back to the parent. A script library such as jquery can make it a lot simpler. For example,

```
$('#yourButton').click(function() {

   var data = [];
   // Assuming grid is CSS class for the grid and selector is CSS class for checkboxes 
   // that selects rows to copy
   $('.grid .selector:checked').parents('tr').each(function() {
        var rowData = [];
        // slice will ignore first td (assuming that it contains the selector checkbox)
        $(this).find('td').slice(1).each(function() { 
            rowData.push($(this).text());
        });
        data.push(rowData);
   });
   // now data will a jagged array - each element will be array of cell values
   // pass the data back to your opener
   ...
});
```

**EDIT**: 
Corrected a small typo (parents instead of parent).
Also see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePu9f/3/) for a working illustration that I have put up for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, although I am not very much familier with jQuery, I will surely give it a try.

Comment: I used your code for working this out, but when I place the quick watch on the data or the rowData array, it says rowData/data is undefined.

Comment: @Warrior, data/rowData are both local variables and will be in scope only within those respective methods. You need to first check if click event handler is getting fired or not and so on... use Firebug on Firebox (or use `debugger` keyword to set a break-point in your script and to debug with Visual Studio (or IE Script Debugger).

Comment: Yeah, I am checking their values in this method itself.I am also able to debug this function and the control does get into this function.After executing data.push(rowData); I am applying the quick watch on these variable, but it says that they are undefined.

Comment: @Warrior, considering that both variables initialized to arrays, I am really puzzled at what you are seeing. Can you create a reproducible case in say jsFiddle?

Comment: @Warrior, sorry - couldn't spent time on this yesterday... Nway see my edit in the answer (see this jsfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ePu9f/3/)